# Volume under $z=x^2+y^2$ and above $4x^2+y^2=1$

Tags: polar-coordinates, volume

I have to find the volume under $z=x^2+y^2$ and above $4x^2+y^2=1$.

I know $4x^2+y^{2}$ is an ellipse, so I thought about, in polar coordinates
$$x=\frac{r\cos(t)}{2}$$
and
$$y=r\sin(t)$$
with $0\leq r\leq1,0\leq t\leq 2\pi$. Then
$$z=\frac{r^{2}\cos^{2}(t)}{4}+r^{2}\sin^{2}(t)=1-\frac{3r^{2}\cos^{2}(t)}{4}$$
And so, the volume would be
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\left(1-\frac{3r^{2}\cos^{2}(t)}{4}\right)rdrdt$$
Is it correct?

Comment: The volume under $z=x^2+y^2$ and above $4x^2+y^2=1$ is $0$. Do you mean $4x^2+y^2\leq 1$? Also, if you want to proceed with a transformation $$x=\frac{r\cos(\theta)}{2},y=r\sin(\theta)$$ for $0\leq r \leq 1$, $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ you need to consider the Jacobian as well.

Comment: @MatthewPilling yes, I meant that and I forgot about the Jacobian. Proceeding that way is correct?

Comment: Yes your approach is correct.

Comment: The problem should state $z \geq 0$ or another value otherwise the volume under paraboloid is not bound.

Comment: In addition to Jacobian, you have a small mistake / typo. It should be $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}r^2\left(1-\frac{3\cos^{2}(t)}{4}\right) r \ dr \ dt$